# Is locking required on a method that adds items to a collection when multiple threads perform the add operation

Tags: c#

I have doubts over weather locking should be done in a  method that adds items to a collection if two different threads that are invoking the method.

Lets say a method:

```
private List<string> NameList = new List<string>();

private void AddItem(string item)
{      
   NameList.Add(item);
}
```

Now what happens if two threads call `AddItem` to add item?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: You can use [Thread-safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: please show us some code otherwise you're qustion is likely to be down voted and closed because it lacks sufficient information for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: It depends on 'whether' any other functions iterate through the collection. Otherwise you will have problems modifying the collection.

Comment: @JeffOnsager That is not true. A `List<T>` (and many other collections) will get corrupt if two threads add to it concurrently. Whether another thread is reading or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten - Good point, thank you.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Having another thread reading it wouldn't make the write corrupt, but it could well make the reader corrupt.  And not just through a concurrent modification exception, but something like reading a value from the buffer that has since been discarded, and that contains completely invalid information.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten You said "Whether another thread is reading or not doesn't matter.", so I was just clarifying.  If you meant something else, it was at least confusing.

Comment: I did not get the meaning of corrupt.If i have list and i add items to it from two threads why would it get corrupt.If i am not checking if items already exist in it.Please clear my doubt

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so the short answer is *yes.* For example, if you're using [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The longer answer is, if you can use one of the collections in [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then *no,* because they are inherently thread-safe.